# Clear absolute floated elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to make a hover effect. When user hovers one div it goes in position absolute and changes it's height. Here is the code:

```css
    @import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css';

.child {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 48px;
}

.child:hover {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}

.child .sub-child { display: none; }
.child:hover .sub-child { display: block; }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="child">
                First
                <ul class="sub-child">
                    <li>First</li>
                    <li>Second</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="child">Second</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="child">
                Third
                <ul class="sub-child">
                    <li>First</li>
                    <li>Second</li>
                    <li>Third</li>
                    <li>Fourth</li>
                    <li>Fifth</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
            <div class="child">Fourth</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">Some text here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when hover goes to the last element from the row or to the last element from the list then content overlaps. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try it this way: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/gp5gxkug/1/

Comment: When using `position: absolute` you can't have the rest of the document take into account that elements flow anymore

Comment: In such cases is the design you're using the problem. For such a situation you cannot change the element's position to `absolute`, as Dan in previous comment said, the other divs will keep the flow and will move.

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve. It's really not clear to me.

Comment: I made another version: http://jsfiddle.net/gp5gxkug/3/ In every child I have a sub-child div which must be shown when user hovers. sub-child div have dynamic content (2 list or 5 or 10 or even 0) and the number of child elements is dynamic too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're taking the right approach here, but I made some adjustments, including adding a parent div to the first row to add some margin so they don't overlap:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QbVewL

```
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css';

.menu{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.child {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 48px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child:hover {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    height: 62px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```